# Visual Studio 2017 Build Pack CLI

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have a NetStandard 2.0 class library project that includes references to two another class library project as follows. (A -> B -> C)  Where  A,B and C are all class library created by me.   When I pack using the VS Menu Build -> Pack or cli msbuild /t:pack the resulting nupkg only contains A.dll.  How to i get the nupkg that includes A,B and C.

Library B  has dependencies Newtonsoft.Json and Microsoft.Csharp and library C has dependencies to RestSharp.  for those external dependencies, is it possible to include in the nupkg ?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the exact command which you are using to create the nuget package?

Comment: I am using the following command  msbuild /t:pack /p:Configuration=Release on the library A

Comment: Try running `dotnet pack -c Release`

Comment: No luck.  Still the nupkg contains only the A.dll.  The bin/Release/netstandard2.0 directory has the B.dll and C.dll but without the other external dependencies.  This holds true for both dotnet and msbuild command.